# If i have to add a content in drupal through custom form which table in database should be used?

Tags: forms

I have created a custom Form through form api which only contains one form field of adding image to node and their will be a different form through which i am going to add body , title and tags in database . Now I am really confused that which table in database should i use to add the data so i can see the data in the content section on the user interface of the site( for admin ).
I tried using some tables as node__field_image for adding the image but turns out it is not working.
Any suggestions how can this be done.

Comment: Don't interact with the DB tables directly. Instead, load an entity, add the values to the correct fields on the entity, then save the entity.

Comment: Yes, don't use raw SQL, use the API.

Comment: OK I will try it by using entity manager , but can someone tell me why can't we directly use database in this use-case.

Comment: Look you don't know what tables to touch and therefore are asking this question. The API doesn't need to ask this question. It knows which tables to touch and which not. You have a CMS with numerous APIs to handle all CRUD operations in a standardised way. You don't want to be the poor future maintainer of your project who years later finds out that someone thought it was a clever idea bypassing the CMS and to store field data in the database on their own.

Comment: You would never write anything directly to the database that Entity API manages. It makes no sense at all and there are dozens of things that happen on save besides just the writes.